# using Regex for adding a space after dot, excluding dot between numbers and link strings

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regexp-replace

I'm using the following regex expression `(?<=[.,?!])(?=[^\s])(?![0-9])` to add a space after a dot if needed (exlcuding space after the puntuaction if the dot is in between numbers)

When doing search & replace (replacing for a space). Everything ok. Only issue is when having some link in my strings. For example `"https://test.com/87786"` or `"/8787786.jpeg"` a space is also being added in there.

Any ideas on how to change my expression for excluding adding spaces after "." in links strings?

Thanks

Comment: How do you propose determining if `test.com` is part of a url or if `test` is the last word of a sentence and `com` is the first word of the next? To cover all cases, I think you're going to need to *parse* the input, rather than use a purely regex approach.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think you can achieve it with just lookbehind, as no engine that I know of supports variable length lookbehinds.

What you seem to want to do is to replace a sequence:

1. start of string or not a slash nor a dot
2. (Non empty) Sequence of alphabetic code points
3. A dot
4. Any alphabetic code point

And insert a space after the dot. You can achieve it by converting the above descriptions into the corresponding regular expressions, then mark the first three as a capture, the fourth as another capture (this is done using parentheses), and then use it in the replacement string (some engines use backslashed numbers to indicate where the captures should go, in this case the replacement would be `"\1 \2"`.

You might need to tweak a little the first “starting” part, and you might also need to replace several times until the string gets stable. Otherwise.strings.like.this.will.still.have.dots.

Update as requested:

```
(?<=^|[^/.a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z]+\.(?=[a-zA-Z])
```

Split by pieces and commented:

```
# positive lookbehind (fixed length) == "preceded by"
(?<=             )
# start of string
    ^
# or
     |
# any except for a slash or a dot or a letter
      [^/.a-zA-Z]
# A word (one or more chaacters)
                  [a-zA-Z]+
# A dot (it needs to be escaped with a backslash)
                           \.
# positive lookahead == "followed by"
                             (?=        )
# a letter
                                [a-zA-Z]
```

This regexp is better than my first idea, as it matches exactly the word and the dot before which you have to put the space. So you can replace with `"\0 "` and have the space added to the end of the match.

See examples at https://regexr.com/65vb6

Comment: hi rewritten, first of all thanks for taking the time to answer.
i'm really sorry but I do not fully understand the idea, could you please help me a little further to depict it into regex? Thank you

Comment: updated @FranOrione